# How can I override the Dimension.Dimscale if a DimStyle is applied

Tags: c#, autocad

I have a `Dimension` that I want to use a particular style but then override the `Dimscale`.  I have tried the following:

```
Dimension dimension = 
  _transaction.GetObject(entityId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Dimension;

dimension.UpgradeOpen();
dimension.DimensionStyleName = "My Style"; //"My Style" uses a Dimscale of 1
dimension.Dimscale = 256;
```

However, when this code runs the dimension style is applied but the `Dimscale` is not overriden.  I've also tried enlisting the last 2 lines in separate transactions and also in separate database saves but I get the same result.  I do not understand why this doesn't work when I know that from the UI I can manually override the `Dimscale`.

How can I successfully override the `Dimension.Dimscale`?

Answer (score 0):

What if you open your dimension style table, select the record "myStyle" and modify the property dimscale?

```
DimStyleTable myDimStyleTable =(DimStyleTable)myTransactionManager.GetObject(db.DimStyleTableId,OpenMode.ForWrite);
```

Comment: The "My Style" needs to have `Dimscale` of 1 because that is what is used by the majority of the dimensions.  I just want to override a few of the dimensions to be `Dimscale` of 256.